# Positioning data request

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, gps, geocode

I have put together an app which locates a user's current position, geocodes a current address and then puts them on a map (using the google maps api) with a calculated route between the two.

It works fine in itself - but I am finding that the first time using it on a new phone or browser, the initial prompt as to whether the user would like to share their positioning data or not is stopping it from actually resolving a position.

Is there a way to pause the script while that prompt is visible or any other ways I could either delay the script or detect when this has happened?

Thanks!! :)

Comment: would it be easier if i gave the link - the script is contained in the html:  http://fruitfulcreations.co.uk/takemehome/appIndex.html

Comment: basically i have the second button, which draws the map and directions, hidden until the first part of the script (the geolocator and geocoder requests) has executed - is there a way i could make it only show if both variables are filled or if both requests return positively instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would start a timer onCreate that checks once a second for permission to be true. Or create a function that starts location update and execute it when button is clicked. I'm not sure if that was your question though.

Comment: How do you do that?  Could you link me to some example code or a tutorial?  Thanks! :)